# The solc is not generatig *.abi file with the option --abi and -o build

Tags: solidity, solc, abi

When I use the --abi option, the abi interface is generated:

```
$ solc Greeter.sol --abi

======= Greeter.sol:mortal =======
Contract JSON ABI
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]
```

But when I ask it to put it into the output folder, with -o build, the file is missing:

```
WHHA@NBVAL752 ~/dev/java-magazine-tutorial
$ solc Greeter.sol --abi -o build

WHHA@NBVAL752 ~/dev/java-magazine-tutorial
$ ls build/
Greeter.sol

WHHA@NBVAL752 ~/dev/java-magazine-tutorial
$ cat build/Greeter.sol
```

The only generated file is Greeter.sol which is emtpy.

The contract code is:

```
$ less Greeter.sol pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract mortal {  /* Define variable owner of the type address*/  address owner;  /* this function is executed at initialization  and sets the owner of the contract */ function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; }

/* Function to recover the funds on the  contract */  function kill() {  if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner);  } } Greeter.sol (END)
```

SOlc version is:

```
$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.4.9+commit.364da425.Windows.msvc
```

Any idea??

Comment: Possibly this issue? https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1629

Answer (score 5):

It seems like a command syntax issue. This works for me:

`solc --abi greeter.sol -o build`

Answer (score 0):

For generating **abi** and **bin** files using solc

```
solc --abi --bin --optimize Calculator.sol -o contracts
```

Please note i executed this code from my root folder where this .sol file is present.